# Is there a way to limit the memory, ghci can have?

Tags: debugging, haskell, memory-management, ghc, ghci

I'm used to debug my code using ghci. Often, something like this happens (not so obvious, of course):

```
ghci> let f@(_:x) = 0:1:zipWith(+)f x
ghci> length f
```

Then, nothing happens for some time, and if I don't react fast enough, ghci has eaten maybe 2 GB of RAM, causing my system to freeze. If it's too late, the only way to solve this problem is [ALT] + [PRINT] + [K].

My question: Is there an easy way to limit the memory, which can be consumed by ghci to, let's say 1 GB? If limit is exceed, the calculation should ve aborted or ghci should be killed.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716216/recovering-from-stack-overflow-or-heap-exhaustion-in-a-haskell-program

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A platform independant way to accomplish this is to supply the `-M` option as on option to the Haskell runtime like this

```
ghci +RTS -M1m
```

see [the GHC documentation’s page on how to control the RTS (runtime system)](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/runtime-control.html) for details.

The `ghci` output now looks like:

```
>ghci +RTS -M10m
GHCi, version 6.12.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Loading package ffi-1.0 ... linking ... done.
Prelude> let f@(_:x) = 0:1:zipWith(+)f x
Prelude> length f
Heap exhausted;
Current maximum heap size is 10485760 bytes (10 MB);
use `+RTS -M<size>' to increase it.
```

Comment: I just created an alias `alias ghci='ghci +RTS -M500m -RTS'` in `~/.bashrc` and anything is fine now. Thank you very much.

Comment: I assume you could also use your `.ghci` file? http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.2.1/html/users_guide/ghci-dot-files.html

Comment: Actually this does not abort when the limit is reached, so it's not a solution. Furthermore ghci still keeps using more memory than stated. For example I have `4Gb` of RAM, I set it to `-M100m`. It tells me it's set to `100Mb`, which completely fine, but when I run a `fib 100000` the program still alomst freezes my machine. It doesn't totally freeze it like before, but memory is almost full and swap is being filled, causing lots of IO, making the system unusable for two or more minutes.

Comment: I now tested it with `length` - in this simple case it does work.

Comment: @Zelphir works for me with GHCi-8.0.1. Probably a bug that was fixed. You can install it with stack, and make an alias e.g. `alias ghci512="stack ghci --ghci-options '+RTS -M512m -RTS'"`. If you're using stack for projects, I'd recommend to stick to its ghci anyway in order to not duplicate libraries and file cache in RAM.

Comment: It should be noted, that heap size is not the only thing that can grow. GHC lets you control the maximum and suggested size of the heap, the size of the stack, and the allocation area of the garbage collector too.

Answer (score 2):

Running it under a shell with `ulimit -m` set is a fairly easy way. If you want to run with some limit on a regular basis, you can create a wrapper script that does `ulimit` before running `ghci`.

Comment: This doesn't works. I tried something like `ulimit -m 102400` and it still consumes memory.

Comment: @hobbs @FUZxxl you should use `ulimit -v`, not `ulimit -m`. `-m` switch limits physical memory, while you need to limit virtual: physical+swap. I use `ulimit -v $(( (1024**2)*2 ))` (zsh) with 4 GiB RAM + 5 GiB swap and it does not freeze the system. This limits the amount of memory to 2 GiB and can be put into `~/.zshrc` or `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Thank you. I find this less helpfull, as I cannot change the value in the shell again afterwards. (Only down...)

Comment: @FUZxxl Why you can't? I have no problems with this (or did you mean that you can't change it from GHCi?). It may be less useful because when the process runs out of memory, it may catch SEGV and crash, but GHCi is handling this normally. There is some related useful feature in zsh: if some application that is modifying tty settings (for example, vim) crashes, you will get a mess on the screen and have some keys not working. Zsh builtin `ttyctl` with argument `-f` will prevent this.

Comment: What I mean is like this: First, I do something like `ulimit -v 102400`, then - after ghci - I want to undo: `ulimit -v unlimited`, but I get a permission error.

Comment: @FUZxxl I can suggest switching to zsh: I managed to reproduce your problem, but on bash only.

Comment: In bash you can use parentheses to spawn a subshell, so this should set a ulimit which applies to ghci only and is lifted when the subshell exits: $ (ulimit -v 1000000; ghci)

Comment: Worth to mention, `-v` option accepts kilobytes. `man ulimit` for some reason says nothing about the units.