# Is there a way to run a Haskell console in a recursion depth or memory limited mode?

Tags: haskell, ghci, hugs

Here is the problem: sometimes, when playing with GHCI, I end up running an infinite computation by mistake. When this happens, most times, my computer crashes and I'm not even able to interrupt it using Ctrl+C.
I wonder if there is a way to run GHCI (or another interactive console like Hugs) in some mode that allows me to interrupt the program before the memory runs out. Maybe setting a virtual limit for the recursion depth or for the memory used.

(This question may be a duplicated of [Is there a way to limit the memory, ghci can have?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766656/is-there-a-way-to-limit-the-memory-ghci-can-have) but this also considers the posibility of a recursion depth limit, not just memory limit.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using the [RTS options to control the garbage collector](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/runtime-control.html#rts-options-gc) when starting GHCi. For instance,

```
ghci +RTS -M100M -RTS Foo.hs
```

should limit the memory to 100MB. Alternatively, use `-Ksize` to limit the stack (by default it is limited by 80% of the heap).