# Haskell, Limit GHCI memory

Tags: haskell, memory, ghci, haskell-stack

I already found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766656/is-there-a-way-to-limit-the-memory-ghci-can-have) and the answers to it.

On the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3766973/1829329) you can see my comment about the solution. It doesn't seem to work for example for this function:

```
fiblist = 0 : 1 : (zipWith (+) fiblist (tail fiblist))

fib :: (Integral a) => a -> String
fib n
  | n < 10000 = show (genericIndex fiblist n)
  | otherwise = error "The number is too high and the calculation might freeze your machine."
```

It still renders the system unusable, even if I only give GHCI 256Mb Heap and 256Mb Stack space. For a simple call of `length` (of an infinite list) it does work.

My question now is: What does the solution for all cases look like? (Is there one? If not, why not?)

**Edit #1: Additional information**

- OS: Xubuntu 14.04
- RAM: 4GB
- Exact command I used for GHCI: `stack ghci +RTS -M256m -K256m`
- GHC Version: `stack ghc -v` results in:

  ```
  Version 1.0.2, Git revision fa09a980d8bb3df88b2a9193cd9bf84cc6c419b3 (3084 commits) x86_64
  ... (a lot of other stuff) ...
  ```

Comment: I don't understand your example. I added an import and loaded it into `ghci fib.hs +RTS -M256M -K256M`. But the largest computation I can do with `fib` is `fib 9999` which can be done in far less than 256MB of space. Can you give an example which actually demonstrates the issue?

Comment: (And, if I make the number 10000 bigger so that I can try `fib 100000`, I get an error `<interactive>: Heap exhausted; Current maximum heap size is 268435456 bytes (256 MB); use `+RTS -M<size>' to increase it.`)

Comment: Windows or Linux? How much physical RAM do you have? What are the exact options are you giving GHCi? What exact expression are you evaluating?

Comment: @ReidBarton @MathematicalOrchid Well, when I didn't have that limitation and tried `fib 1000000` it froze my computer for 3 minutes before I could barely spam `ctrl-c` and `ctrl-d` to make it stop. It filled almost all of my RAM (`4Gb`) despite having the limitations in place. I am using a `Xubuntu 14.04`. Exact options I gave GHCI are: `+RTS -M256m -K256m` Without the limitations, my machine becomes a brick.

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't sound right. What version of GHC?

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid added that information as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
> stack ghci +RTS -M256m -K256m
> ```

That's not setting the RTS options of GHCi, but `stack`. After all, `stack` is also written in Haskell and therefore can take RTS options too.

Use `--ghci-options` to provide additional options to GHCi instead:

```
stack ghci --ghci-options="+RTS -M256m -K256m -RTS"
```

The closing `-RTS` is necessary since `stack` provides some more options to GHCi.

Comment: Is it possible to also dump some information of which allocation caused the overflow once the limit is reached?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is in the invocation.

```
stack ghci +RTS -M256m -K256m
```

Stack does not pass these parameters through to ghci:

```
/.../.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-7.10.2/lib/ghc-7.10.2/bin/ghc -B/.../.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-7.10.2/lib/ghc-7.10.2 --interactive -odir=/.../.stack/global/.stack-work/odir/ -hidir=/.../.stack/global/.stack-work/odir/
```

If you instead invoke ghci directly:

```
/usr/local/lib/ghc-7.10.3/bin/ghc -B/usr/local/lib/ghc-7.10.3 --interactive +RTS -M256m -K256m
```

Yay!  Arguments!

I suspect your `+RTS ...` is actually being consumed by stack's own RTS - as in, stack is written in Haskell and is following these constraints when you actually desire ghci to follow said constraints.  So... submit an issue for stack.